# How to disable/override the ctrl+shift+i binding in VS.Code for Windows?

Tags: visual-studio-code, key-bindings

ctrl+shift+i seems to be hard bound to open the VS.Code Inspector/debugger in Windows.  I use an inverted-T on the home row for cursor control [1] and need this chord free for "select up":

```
{"key": "ctrl+shift+i",     "command": "cursorUpSelect",
                            "when": "editorTextFocus"},
```

How do I override this keybinding?

1 http://xahlee.info/kbd/osx_keybinding.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With VSCode 0.3.0 we no longer bind this keybinding by default!

Answer (score 1):

To disable, add

```
{"key": "ctrl+shift+i",     "when": "editorTextFocus"}
```

to `/Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/Code/User/keybindings.json`. The lack of a `command` property indicates no action will be taken when editor text area has focus.

Comment: That didn't work for me (using Windows), the Inspector still shows on ctrl+shift+i. In any case, I still need that key chord for select line up.

Comment: We forgot to remove some debugging hard-coded keybindings. We'll remove them with our next update. Sorry about that!